# Skipping steps in Oracle Apex Data Load Sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In Apex 5.1, going through the Data Load Wizard results to 4 pages/steps. 
(1) Data Load Source
(2) Data/Table Mapping
(3) Data Validation
(4) Data Load Results
For our project, incoming data is already validated and table mapping won't be necessary. What would be the ideal way to skip steps 2-3 and directly going to the Step 4: Data Load Results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can skip step 2, otherwise Apex won't know which columns in the file are supposed to be loaded into which table columns.

You can easily skip step 3 by putting a submit action in the Before section on p3.

Comment: Skipping step 3 by adding in a submit action works. And thanks for the info with regards to skip 2.